# My Python codes for making a bokeh plot are giving a blank plot

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, bokeh

I am using Jupyter Notebook to run my Python codes. The issue with my codes is that the output is giving a blank plot (not any error message from Python).

My codes stand as follows:

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

data = myBenchmarkData
factors = ["Group"]
x =  ["Rate"]

dot = figure(title="Categorical Dot Plot", tools="", toolbar_location=None,
        y_range=factors, x_range=[0,200])

dot.segment(0, factors, x, factors, line_width=2, line_color="green", )
dot.circle(x, factors, size=15, fill_color="orange", line_color="green", line_width=3, )

 output_file("categorical.html", title="categorical.py example")
 show(row(dot, sizing_mode="scale_width"))
```

When I run these bunch of codes, it does execute correctly by creating a new html file but the page shows a blank plot with the word "Group" mentioned on the y-axis.
My data comes from a csv file and it has been imported correctly. "Group" and "Rate" are series (column names) from my dataframe.

I did a test and hardcoded the list for factors and x, and the plot worked fine. It seems my codes are not understanding that I want to retrieve the factors list from the "Group" column and the x list from the "Rate" column of my dataframe.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browsers JavaScript console?

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: To better debug when using Jupyter Notebook, instead of using output_file, use `from bokeh.io import output_notebook`. And then use `output_notebook()` So, whenever you issue `show(some_layout)` it will show in the notebook. When I use `output_file` in a notebook, the notebook gets stuck and I have to restart it. So I prefer using `output_notebook()` for that reason. Later on, when things are working, you can use `output_file` to generate the html file.

Comment: @PabloReyes Thanks. I tried what you suggested but it does not output a plot. The only message I get in my Jupter Notebook is "BokehJS successfully loaded."

Comment: @PabloReyes Ok, I missed to add the line show(dot). Now, it does display a plot but it is still a blank one! May be I am using the wrong chart to display these series?

Comment: I'll suggest to start playing with very simple data.  Just a few points to display.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is hard to solve a problem with your actual data and is better to create some simple example data. This works at least in the bokeh version I'm using 0.12.4

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

output_notebook()

x = [60,50,75,150,100]
factors = ["cars","buses","airplanes","trains","bicycles"]

dot = figure(title="Categorical Dot Plot", tools="", toolbar_location=None,
        y_range=factors, x_range=[0,204])
dot.segment(0, factors, x, factors, line_width=2, line_color="green", )
dot.circle(x, factors, size=15, fill_color="orange", line_color="green", line_width=3, )

show(row(dot, sizing_mode="scale_width"))
```

[image]

Comment: @user3115933 I created a simple example using only 5 objects. I'm using bokeh version 0.12.4. I'm not aware if this was not working on previous versions, but its always good to know what version are you using.